# Can't create directory with Hadoop command?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I've been starting NameNode and DataNode, but when I try to use HDFS command to make a directory(in any place), it doesn't work.

Here is my command:

```
./hdfs dfs  -mkdir -p /usr/master/datas
```

and I also trying to change the format of my path:

```
./hdfs dfs  -mkdir -p "/usr/master/datas"
```

but I get same result.

I'm just starting to learn big-data. Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue and how debug the issue?

Comment: any  message   when you run those  command

Comment: An error message would help.  Did you look at the namenode logs too?

Answer (score 1):

`/usr` doesn't exist on HDFS. That's a Unix directory.

The user directory in HDFS is `/user`.

Plus, you need to be an HDFS superuser to create HDFS folders under the root path, or at least folders not owned by the current user.

Comment: I checked, I can see the directory in HDFS web page, Thank you.